# Dynamics WebAPI: Update only changed fields?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I am writing an application that accesses Dynamics 365 CE via the webapi (v9.0 / 9.1). My application retrieves a record and displays that to the user, the user can make changes and save the record again.

In that case, my application will attempt to save the changes using a Patch call against the Dynamics WebAPI.

Is there a built in way of updating only the fields that the user had changes? This is in a web application where I can't be sure to be able to have a proper client side change tracking, meaning I either have to do another call against the CRM, compare both records and send only the updated values to the CRM *or* send the entire record to the CRM. The second case is obviously much more performant and easier but I can't seem to find a way to tell the WebAPI to only update the changed fields..

Comment: If you've retrieved the original values from CRM, can't you compare against that and prepare your PATCH accordingly?

Comment: yes that's what I resorted to doing in the end. I was hoping that there was a way to have this handled automatically by the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieval of record attributes using web API & binding the values to UI controls, identifying the **dirty** attributes & update back the source system with only those dirty fields - this is what usual cycle will be.

What you have is issue in identifying the dirty fields - it is not actual change tracking. Try to identify them in client side using an efficient way before submitting a update server request (PATCH).

Sending whole record field values irrespective of its dirtiness is not recommended for various reasons like losing Audit track, pipeline business logic in CRM Plugin/Workflow, etc.

Comment: Right, I'm aware of the issue with plugins, audit track, etc. Thats why I was hoping there would be a way of automatically identifying the dirty fields on an API level. Doing that manually is a lot of work since I can't rely on the UI giving me an accurate representation of what has really been changed by the user

Comment: @buddybubble unfortunately there is no option to do that with web api payload